# error query mysql on pentaho data integration (cdb)

Tags: mysql, pentaho

mysql query is :

```
SELECT
    dim_location.country_name,
    COUNT(fact_flight.sk_fact)
FROM
    dim_location, dim_date
    INNER JOIN fact_flight ON dim_location.sk_location = fact_flight.sk_location
WHERE
    fact_flight.date_key = dim_date.date_key
GROUP BY
    dim_location.country_name
```

but it's doesn't work and this is error message

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'dim_location.sk_location' in 'on clause'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please re-order the tables in the FROM clause as in the query given below; otherwise, the join condition in the ON clause that is meant to be applied to joining the `dim_location` and `fact_flight` tables, will be wrongly applied to the `dim_date` and `fact_flight` tables which would result in the above error:

```
SELECT
    dim_location.country_name,
    COUNT(fact_flight.sk_fact)
FROM
    dim_date, dim_location
    INNER JOIN fact_flight ON dim_location.sk_location = fact_flight.sk_location
WHERE
    fact_flight.date_key = dim_date.date_key
GROUP BY
    dim_location.country_name
```