# query sql error on pentaho data integration

Tags: mysql, pentaho

my sql query is

```
SELECT
    dim_location.country_name,
    COUNT(fact_flight.sk_fact)
FROM
    dim_date, dim_location
    INNER JOIN fact_flight ON dim_location.sk_location = fact_flight.sk_fact AND 
    dim_date.date_key = fact_flight.date_key

WHERE
    fact_flight.date_key = dim_date.date_key
GROUP BY
    dim_location.country_name
```

we want to show location based day name but it's doesn't work and find error :

> #1054 - Unknown column 'dim_date.date_key' in 'on clause'

Comment: Don't mix legacy joins and the new syntax.

Comment: looks familiar to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756350/error-query-mysql-on-pentaho-data-integration-cdb

Comment: I almost got a sense of deja vu!

Answer (score 0):

Please re-order the tables in the FROM clause as in the query given below;

SELECT
    dim_location.country_name,
    COUNT(fact_flight.sk_fact)
FROM
    dim_date, dim_location
    INNER JOIN fact_flight ON dim_location.sk_location = fact_flight.sk_location
WHERE
    fact_flight.date_key = dim_date.date_key
GROUP BY
    dim_location.country_name ;

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i hope the result based day_name in database. When  i try your query the result not based day_name in database, how to solve this problem?